# Copy values in columns C and F in range1 to columns P and R in range2?

Tags: excel, vba

I am having issues with the bolded line of code below: I get an error that states, "Application-defined or object-defined error"

I sort of morphed this code from a previous code of mine...

```
Option Explicit

Sub BringDownSNs()
Call OptimizeCode_Begin

Dim cell1 As Range, rng1 As Range, cell2 As Range, rng2 As Range
Dim array1, array2, counter1 As Long, counter2 As Long
Dim StartTime As Double
Dim MinutesElapsed As String

Set rng1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B" & Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row)
Set rng2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("M2:M" & Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).row)

array1 = rng1.Offset(0, 4).Resize(, 5).Value 'creating an array by taking rng1 (column B) and offsetting it by 4 (to include up to column F), then resizing to include columns B through F (5 columns total)
array2 = rng2.Offset(0, 5).Resize(, 6).Value 'same as above but using rng2

For counter2 = 1 To UBound(array2) 'for each row in array2 - from row 1 in array 2 to upper bound of array 2 (row 3865)
    For counter1 = 1 To UBound(array1) 'for each row in array1 - from row 1 in array 1 to upper bound of array 1 (row 2390)

    'if array 2 -> sheet 1, current row (starting with row 1 of the array), column 1 of the array (Column M, NHA Part Number) equals array 1 -> sheet 1, current row, column 1 of the array (Column B, NHA Part Number) _
     AND if array 2 -> sheet 1, current row, column 5 of the array (Column Q , Part Number) equals array 1 -> sheet 1, current row, column 4 of the array (Column E, Part Number) THEN _
     copy data from current row in array 1 (columns C & F) into current row in array 2 (columns P & R)

        If array2(counter2, 1) = array1(counter1, 1) And array2(counter2, 5) = array1(counter1, 4) Then
            **Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C:C" & counter1 + 1 & "F:F" & counter1 + 1).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("P:P" & counter2 + 1 & "R:R" & counter2 + 1)**
        Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next

Call OptimizeCode_End
End Sub
```

Comment: What is this trying to achieve? `.Range("C:C" & counter1 + 1 & "F:F" & counter1 + 1)`

Comment: Are you after the two lines `Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter1 + 1, "C").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter2 + 1,"P")` and `Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter1 + 1,"F").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter2 + 1,"R")`?  (Or, if you are only wanting the **data** copied, `Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter2 + 1, "P").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter1 + 1,"C").Value` and `Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter2 + 1,"R").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter1 + 1,"F")`)

Comment: And you should update the comment in `array1 = rng1.Offset(0, 4).Resize(, 5).Value 'creating an array by taking rng1 (column B) and offsetting it by 4 (to include up to column F), then resizing to include columns B through F (5 columns total)` - the comment should actually read `'creating an array by taking rng1 (column B) and offsetting it by 4 (to refer to column F), then resizing to include columns F through J (5 columns total)`

Comment: @YowE3K Yea so I just want to copy the value of C and place it in P and the value of F and place it in Column R...then move onto the next row. It looks like your code is exactly what I want, but I keep getting a "mismatch" error

Comment: Is the mismatch on the `If` statement line?  Are you really wanting to compare column R with column F, and column V with column I?

Comment: @Ralph - I didn't want to post an answer until I knew that that was what the OP was after.  I'll do that now.  (But I'm worried whether my code is the code causing the new mismatch error :S)

Comment: @YowE3K nvm it worked I just had to delete the "and" I had in their accidently

Comment: OK - I have posted it as an answer.  But you really need to look at your comment as well.  (Which is my sarcastic way of saying "you probably need to get rid of the `.Offset` part of that code".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that instead of

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C:C" & counter1 + 1 & "F:F" & counter1 + 1).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("P:P" & counter2 + 1 & "R:R" & counter2 + 1)
```

you are really after

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter1 + 1, "C").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter2 + 1, "P")
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter1 + 1, "F").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter2 + 1, "R")
```

Or, if you are only wanting the data copied:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter2 + 1, "P").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter1 + 1, "C").Value
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter2 + 1, "R").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter1 + 1, "F")
```